MultiLabelBinarizer: inverse_transform How can get a list of labels sorted according to their probability?
I am doing a multi label classification and I use MultiLabelBinarizer to translate the list of labels into Zeros and Ones.
I could get the Labels using inverse_transform which is super. However, in a case where I want to rank the class based on their probability, i.e the higher the probability, the better the judgement of the label even (just) in case its probability is less than 0.5.
How can I get back the sorted list of labels based on their probability?

What probabilities?

prediction probabilities from predict_proba

I don't think MultiLabelBinarizer records that information in the first place, as it only checks for existence of a label.
You need to calculate the probabilities yourself, here's one way:
import itertools
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

a = [["sci-fi", "fantasy", "action"], ["sci-fi", "romance", "action"], ["action"]]
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(a)

flat = list(itertools.chain(*a))

probabilities = [(c, flat.count(c) / len(mlb.classes_)) for c in mlb.classes_}

>>> probabilities
[('action', 0.75), ('fantasy', 0.25), ('romance', 0.25), ('sci-fi', 0.5)]

And one way to get them sorted by the probability:
from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(probabilities, key=itemgetter(1))
[('fantasy', 0.25), ('romance', 0.25), ('sci-fi', 0.5), ('action', 0.75)]

Of course you are probably using numpy or pandas or something similar, in which case the flattening and sorting can be done differently.
